# bash: execute specifc command depending upon the input

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am able to make the code works for me in command line but what I am trying to achieve is a bit more and I am not getting how to achieve that.

For Example, I have a string `MySQL Server@db1com:1111` And this contained hostname is `db1.com`.

Instead of copying only hostname everytime, I am using javascript functionality to extract the hostname only, I mean as below

```
function getHostname() {

    dbiNode = process.argv.slice(2).toString();
    hostname = dbiNode.split(/[@:]/)[1];
    console.log(hostname)
}

getHostname()
```

And for now to automatically SSH I am using below command

```sh
ssh "$(node gethostname.js "MySQL Server@db1:1111")""
```

And it works with out any issue. What I am trying to achieve here is if I type "MySQL Server@db1:1111" in terminal, somehow I need to make my bash execute function via `.bashrc` where I can handle extracting hostname and SSH into that.

But how, I am not getting.

Any reference links/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need node here, just add the following to your .bashrc

```
MySQL() {
  host="${1##*@}"     # remove everything before @
  host="${host%%:*}"  # remove everything after  :
  ssh "$host"
}
```